# how can login to google account in c#? need sample

Tags: c#, account

i try to login  google account with c# windows  app. but i have this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80BvH.jpg)

When I am trying to login via browser in my  application it keeps saying "Couldn't sign you in" This browser or app may not be secure. i need sample

Answer (score 1):

Google won't let you sign-in via an embedded browser for exactly the reason stated - it's not secure. To do so programmatically you need to use their API. Unfortunately this problem is far larger in scope than what an answer here on SO warrants, so here's some links:

Documentation on the .NET API (including samples) can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#auth)

More info on supported browsers and why this might not be one of them can be found [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en)

Comment: my problem is api . i cant find video how use it

Comment: "How do I connect my program to Google's API" is too broad a question, and the documentation I linked gives a step-by-step guide on exactly what you're looking for. Try to follow the process it takes you through and if you run into a specific problem along the way I'm sure there'll be people here that can help. You likely won't find a video on it because it's all there in writing, and will differ from app to app (not to mention exposing private API keys etc.).